# pyarrow Table adds column '__index_level_0__'

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

If I create a pandas df and convert that to a pyarrow Table, I got an additional column '**index_level_0**'.

How do I get rid of it?

```
from pyarrow import Table
import pandas as pd

df_empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b", "c",])
df_empty = df_empty.astype(
    {"a": "int64", "b": "datetime64[ns]", "c": "int64"}
)
df = Table.from_pandas(df_empty)
```

[image]

Comment: since your issue is resolved you may accept an answer? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with *preserve_index=False*

```
return Table.from_pandas(df_empty, preserve_index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try out "preserve_index=False"

```
from pyarrow import Table
import pandas as pd

df_empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b", "c",])
df_empty = df_empty.astype(
  {"a": "int64", "b": "datetime64[ns]", "c": "int64"}
)
df = Table.from_pandas(df_empty, preserve_index = False)
```